# save user_id as a ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I have a survey with a response model, which I like to link to an existing user. She should be able to view her past responses to a survey on a profile page. Well, that's the plan anyway. But I can't even link user to response.

(django==1.5, django-lazysignup)

The user is currently a ForeignKey in Response in order to get the linking

```
# models.p
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Response(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

#views.py
@allow_lazy_user
def survey_detail(request, slug):
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        response = form.save(commit=False)
        response.user = request.user
        response.save()
        ...
```

Error:

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
```

The field user_id is included in table response. Due to south schemamigration I had to set  a one-off value and choose an existing user_id.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is lazy user created? What is `response.form = save()`? I think it should be `response.save()`

Comment: Yes, you are right: it is `response.save()`. I edited it. And yes, lazy user is created.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works using `null=True, blank=True`

```
class Response(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have looks good. The first thing I'd do to troubleshoot is inspect the User object right before you save it. `print type(request.user), request.user`. You could also inspect your Response model object to be sure it's what you expect. That'll indicate if you need to examine the form code or the decorator.

I'm not sure what you mean by "setting a one-off value" for South migration. South won't have anything to do with this. Are you talking about a hack with a fixed user_id to get the form to save? That's not right.

As you say in your own answer, setting `null=True, blank=True` on the user FK field will work, but in effect that means Responses can be submitted from "no one". Doing that seems like fixing a symptom.

Are you using [django-lazysignup](http://django-lazysignup.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) ("django-lazyuser" doesn't appear to be a thing)? Here's a potential pitfall. In short, that package creates temporary users that can hit a `convert/` URL to choose a username and password to become official Users. Because not everyone will do that, there's a management command to clear out unconverted lazy users. That command will delete the LazyUser model object *and* the real User model object. By default, Django will cascade delete related objects, e.g. your Response object. To prevent Responses being silently deleted if they are associated with uncoverted lazy users, set the cascade property on the ForeignKey ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)). Something like `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)` and make sure the `ProtectedError` is safely handled. This only matters if you use that cleanup management command, but better safe than sorry and the next person to maintain the code might run cleanup because who doesn't like cleaning up.

Comment: +1 for your answer. Yes, I'm using django-lazysignup. I fixed it in my question. You are right about the cleanup routine. I didn't thought about that. I need to create my own survey application as basis for my bachelor thesis. My prof said it'd be nice if users were able to sign up to see past voting choices (the survey is about information security). Now I have to options: (i) There is a login requirement before you can vote or (ii) everyone can vote. Login requires the user to sign up which she might be to lazy to do. Hence, lazysignup to be able to keep answers after voting.

Comment: It might make sense to allow survey taking without the overhead of creating an account. You can assess your audience, but account creation is a big hurdle. As long as cleanup doesn't delete data, maybe it's enough to have lazyuser info and the response date. Smart to use LazySignUp! After survey submission you could always provide a "thanks, add a username and password to see your past answers" page. Nice feature.

Comment: Thanks J. I'll keep lazysignup for now. And I'll check if I can disable the cleanup routine and document it in the source code.